# Association Extensions no longer working in Rails 2.3.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that we just upgrade from 2.1.0 to 2.3.10.  After the upgrade, an Association Extension that previously worked causes a failure.  Here is the code on the model for the extension:

```
Class Classroom

  has_many :registrations

  has_many :students, :through => :registrations, :uniq => true do
    def in_group(a_group)
      if a_driver
        scoped(:conditions => ['registrations.group_id = ?', a_group])
      else
        in_no_group
      end
    end

    def in_no_group
      scoped(:conditions => 'registrations.group_id is null')
    end
  end

end
```

This is a simplified model of my actual issue, but basically I used to be able to do

```
classroom.students.in_group(honor_students)
```

This no longer works, with the following output:

```
classroom.students.in_group(honor_students)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'registrations.group_id' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE (registrations.group_id = 1234)
```

When I just grab the list of students, the SQL has all the expected join syntax there thats missing from the above version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `students`.* FROM `students` INNER JOIN `registrations` ON `students`.id = `registrations`.student_id WHERE ((`registrations`.classroom_id = 9876))
```

Why is the association extension missing all the join SQL?

Answer (score 1):

use this [Rails 2.3: How to turn this SQL statement into a named_scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937537/rails-2-3-how-to-turn-this-sql-statement-into-a-named-scope) on students instead of nesting it in association